# if-else inside for loop in algorithm package

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I am trying for a if-else statement inside a for loop. This my code and there is some problem with inner for loop and if-else statement. Code is as follows

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
\label{alg:euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State U: a set of authentic users
\State T: a set containing trustor and trustee information
    \Procedure{DepthDetection}{$T_t_h, U_i$}
    % \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \State $T_u_i  \gets list\ of\ trustee\ taking\ U_i\ as\ trustor$
    \State $I_u_i  \gets list\ of\ items\ rated\ by\ U_i$
    \State Build ${U_i}'s\  trust\ network\ using\ $T_t_h$

    \For{each item $i$ in $I_u_i$ }
    \State $NU_u_i  \gets list\ of\ users\ who\ rated\ I_i$
        \For{each user $u$ in $NU_u_i$ }
            \IF{$u$ is in $T_u_i$}
                \STATE use the rating and trust of $u$ for prediction of rating
            \ENDIF
        \EndFor
    \EndFor

    \State \textbf{return} $L$
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}\end{algorithm}
```

And the output I get is
[image]

As you can see there is a continuation of if condition and statements after the inner loop. I want that to be in nested format.

Comment: Double subscripts should be written $T_{ui}$ or $T_{u_i}$ depending the desired effect.  $T_u_i$ throws an error and disturbs the rest of the typesetting.

Comment: Even after changing that it's not showing the desired effect.

Comment: Now the error telling "undefiened control sequence" for if-else block

Comment: Please complete your code to a minimal document demonstrating the problem - you have internal definitions in play that we need to see.  Also check that that document does not produce errors - look in the `.log` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing `algorithmic` and `algpseudocode` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
\label{alg:euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $U$: a set of authentic users
\State $T$: a set containing trustor and trustee information
    \Procedure{DepthDetection}{$T_{t_h}$, $U_i$}
    \State $T_{u_i} \gets$ list of trustee taking $U_i$ as trustor
    \State $I_{u_i} \gets$ list of items rated by $U_i$
    \State Build $U_i$'s trust network using $T_{t_h}$
    \For{each item $i$ in $I_{u_i}$}
    \State $NU_{u_i} \gets$ list of users who rated $I_i$
        \For{each user $u$ in $NU_{u_i}$ }
            \If{$u$ is in $T_{u_i}$}
                \State use the rating and trust of $u$ for prediction of rating
            \EndIf
        \EndFor
    \EndFor
    \State \textbf{return} $L$
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I also fixed misuses of math mode and the double subscripts.

[image]

Comment: what is the meaning of "mixing algorithmic and algpseudocode syntax" ? Can you please explain where I did that ?

Comment: @thepurpleowl In the nested if statement you were using `\IF`, `\STATE` and `\ENDIF` which are from `algorithmic`, not from `algpseudocode`.

Comment: What is the difference between \usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode} and \usepackage{algorithm}\usepackage{algpseudocode} ? @egreg

Comment: @thepurpleowl None.